# Find $f(x)$ for every $x ∈ R − ${$0$}

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $f : \Bbb R − \{0\} \to  \Bbb R$ be a function satisfying:
>   $$(\forall x \in \Bbb R - \{0\}) \hspace{.5in}f(x) + 2f\left(\frac 1x\right) = x$$
>   Find $f(x)$ for every $x \in \Bbb R − \{0\}$.

Would I be able to just substitute $\frac 1x$ instead of $x$ so that $f(\frac 1x) + 2f(x) = \frac 1x$, or $2f(\frac 1x)+4f(x)=2 \frac 1x$. Then I could obtain $f(x)$ through this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You have:

$f(\frac{1}{x})+2f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, and

$2f(\frac{1}{x})+f(x)=x$.

So we can subtract twice the first equation from the second to get: $$-3f(x)=x-\frac{2}{x}=\frac{x^2-2}{x}.$$

Hence, $$f(x)=\frac{2-x^2}{3x}.$$

Which can be verified by using this for $f$ in either equation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes why not ? f(x) = ((2/x) - x)/3